# How to group and dry common view code in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, user-interface, view

I have two models **Episode** and **Playlist** with the following two views:

For **Episode**:

```
<div class="name">
    <%= link_to episode.name, episode_path(episode) %>
</div>

<div class="description">
    <%= link_to episode.description episode_path(episode) %>
</div>
```

For **Playlist**:

```
<div class="name">
    <%= link_to playlist.name, playlist_path(playlist) %>
</div>

<div class="description">
    <span>Some special span</span>
    <%= raw(playlist.description) %>
</div>
```

The common things between this two views are the

```
<div class="name">. <div class="description">
```

but the content of this two divss is different for each view.

**Question**: How could I extract this two common divs into another view, called _section?

What have I tried:

1. Cells -> they give me a nice view model with properties, but I could not find a way to added additional HTML elements between the places where the properties will be put.
2. Yield and Content_for-> I have tried to create a separate _section layout with:

_section.html.erb

```
<div class="name">
    <%= yield :name %>
</div>

<div class="description">
    <%= yield :description %>
</div>
```

and then two views. The **Episode** view will render the following

```
<% render layout: "section" do %>
 <% content_for :name do %>
     <%= link_to episode.name, episode_path(episode) %>
 <% end %>
 <% content_for :description do %>
     <%= link_to episode.description episode_path(episode) %>
 <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This kind of works until you get to caching (they said content_for does not work with caching and I need to cache this) and the other problem I had was that you should include an additional empty not named yield.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with moving all the logic for playlist and episode views into a single view - called section that basically does the following:

```
<div class="name">
    <%= link_to object.name, polymorphic_path(object) %>
</div>

<div class="description">
    <% if is_episode? %>
        <h1>Some special h1 for episode</h1>
    <% elsif is_playlist? %>
        <h2>Some special other html for playlist for episode</h2>
    <% end %>
    <%= raw(playlist.description) %>
</div>
```

Wow those "ifs" are ugly. I am not sure if I understood the problem correctly, but it is surprising I could not find a cleaner solution.